# What to expect from the "Getting to know you" interview

Tags: interviewing, job-search, new-job

I've been cold-calling/emailing a few companies and am in the process of a job search. For a few of them during the upcoming week I have a "Getting to know you" phone call. The problem is: I have no idea what to expect or what they might answer. Up to this point I've had a few HR interviews, but nothing panned out, so I'm not sure what to expect or anything from this being different.

What should I be looking out for? How should I prepare? Any other advice that may be helpful?

These are small-ish technical companies, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I did not send resume yet, nor did they ask.

Answer (score 7):

In my somewhat limited experience, I would not overthink this.
The purpose of a 'Getting to know you' interview is just that.

Prepare to describe your previous experiences and find out something about the company ( which I assume you've already done when emailing them? ) so you know roughly what business they're in. Perhaps you can even find out some of the technology they are using, but in my experience, you will hear that from them - if not, that makes for a good question.

In my experience, those initial interviews are mostly about finding out whether the company's and your interests align and you could be a good fit in the eyes of the interviewer.

I would ask some general questions about the work environment and tools they use - don't worry too much if you're not familiar with one of them, just indicate any that you are familiar with and that you're happy to learn.

Have a nice chat, listen to what they tell you, ask some questions to show interest and look forward to another interview.

Comment: Pretty much covers it, relax and show your best side.